# Datatables: combining Row Reorder and Form Inputs

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to combine both

Row Reorder
https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html

and

Form inputs
https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

I want to be able to have the drag-and-drop row ordering and editable data.

Here's the problem I can't figure out: every time I drag-and-drop reorder a row, it reverts the data back to the initial state instead of what the user typed into the text fields.  I want the data entry fields to stay the same!

Anyone have a solution for that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    rowReorder: true,
    lengthMenu: [[-1, 25, 100, 200], ["All", 25, 100, 200]],
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 0 },
        { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
    ],
});
```

The HTML is standard table, tr, td, input type=text type stuff.

EDIT:

This was due to a bug in the library which has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in Version: 1.1.0 of the RowReorder plugin for Datatables.